# Using .is() to check for multiple IDs

Tags: jquery

I want to know where to locate the Logical Not Operator in the following code:

The pursuing functionality is that while clicking away in any part of the page except of those elements, #chat_content should hide.

The code is generate dynamically using PHP. Would be nice to know :-)

```
$(window).click(function (e){
    var targ=$(e.target);
    if(!targ.is("#chat","#chat_content","#mensajes")){
        $("#chat_content").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#mensajes").css("margin-top","3px");
    }
})
```

Comment: `targ.is("#chat","#chat_content","#mensajes")` is not a valid usage of the method

Comment: That does not look like a valid selector in jQuery, you probably want something like `.is("#chat, #chat_content, #mensajes")`.

Comment: I miss it Thank You both! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a logical operator here. The issue is because you're passing multiple arguments to `is()` when it only accepts a single one.

To do what you require, place all the selectors in a *single* string, separated by commas:

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
  var targ = $(e.target);
  if (!targ.is("#chat, #chat_content, #mensajes")) {
    $("#chat_content").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#mensajes").css("margin-top", "3px");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank You! I miss it! :S The issue was in the syntax declaration!

Comment: No problem, glad to help